# Excel VBA: Update chart button when new row of data is added to datasheet

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm working on an Excel VBA macro that will create a timeline for a list of projects.  I would like the macro to be dynamic and have an update command button that will refresh the chart when new information is added to the data sheet.

However, anytime I add a new row to the data sheet, the chart format goes haywire.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Charts.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim ChartSheet1 As Chart
    Set ChartSheet1 = Charts.Add

    With ChartSheet1
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A61,F2:F61,I2:I61")
        .ChartType = xlBarStacked
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The "ThisWorkbook.Charts.Delete" is to delete the existing chart and have it replaced with the new, updated chart.

Column A contains the project titles.  Column F contains the date that the project starts on.  Column I contains the number of days that the project will last for.

I have 59 rows of data in my data sheet.  I made the range to 61 so that I could add another row or two of data to see if my code works.  But it doesn't.  I used the record macro function to make most of my code.  I understand this isn't the best technique but I have no background in VBA and was looking for a quick solution.  I've been trying to learn the basics but can't find a solution for the problem I'm having.

I'm thinking that the problem is with "61" and that I should change that to a variable like "lastRow". Or maybe I'm completely off due to my lack of experience with programming.  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the data source dynamic by calculating the last row of the data in VBA like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' declare variables for last row and worksheet
    Dim lastRow
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' get last populated cell in column A
    lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Charts.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim ChartSheet1 As Chart
    Set ChartSheet1 = Charts.Add


    With ChartSheet1
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",F2:F" & lastRow & ",I2:I" & lastRow)
        .ChartType = xlBarStacked
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Your code completely deletes the chart sheet and then creates a new one. I'm not sure what "the chart format goes haywire" means in your world, but without any formatting you'll get the Excel default horizontal bar chart with that code.

Comment: I changed my code to yours and that allows the chart to dynamically find the last row.  However, the formatting is going to the Excel default horizontal bar chart, as you suggested.  Any suggestions on how I might keep it as a "xlBarStacked" chart?

Comment: It still is a stacked bar chart. The second line in the With statement does that here: `.ChartType = xlBarStacked`. Your macro deletes the chart sheet and creates a new chart. Any formatting will need to be applied to the new chart. That would be a new question. Close this one first.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the data in the worksheet into a Table (Insert tab > Table). Make the chart using this table.

Now whenever a row is added to or deleted from the table, the chart automatically updates to reflect the current contents of the table.

No need for VBA, no need to delete and recreate the chart, and lose then try to restore its formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the numbers. The Range goes from Row 2 to Row 61, which covers 59 rows of data. If you want to add another 2 more rows of data, you need to change it to "63".